# Matrix inequality with different dimension and square root

Tags: trace, matrix-norms, linear-matrix-inequality

I am trying to prove the matrix inequality which came from the Gelbrich distance. The inequality seems to be correct as I substituted some random values, but not 100% sure with that. The inequality is as follows:

For the symmetric positive definite matrix $X$,$Y$,$M$,$N$,$A$,$D$

$|| \sqrt{X} - \sqrt{Y} ||_2^2 \geq || \sqrt{M} - \sqrt{N} ||_2^2$

where
$M =
    \begin{bmatrix}
       A & B \\\ B^{\top} & D + X 
    \end{bmatrix},
    N = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\\ B^{\top} & D+Y
    \end{bmatrix}$

Matrix 2-norm is defined as follows : $||X||_2^2 = trace(X^TX)$.
The B matrix doesn't have to be square, and the only difference between M and N is the X and Y at the (2,2) position. The key point is that the size of the matrix between LHS and RHS are different.

I have tried some matrix inequalities such as Powers–Størmer’s inequality https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379512006167,  or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361559/a-square-root-inequality-for-symmetric-matrices. But failed to prove it. It would be really helpful if anyone of you can give me some advice.

Have a good day, Thanks!

Comment: are roots of matrices unique?

Comment: Good point! I think it would be okay to only think about the roots which is positive definite symmetric matrix, which is unique.

Comment: unique up to a sign